# How to pass multiple keyboard inputs along with linux command

Tags: linux, bash

I run a linux command that sometimes asks for user input (press y or n).

After that for the same command I need to pass (yes/no)

I always want to answer y,and after that yes, how can I pass this value automatically ?

For 1 argument I knew that we can use 
echo y|command

But,for multiple inputs I do not know how????

After Passing y, I should also able to give yes
Is there a way???

Comment: Pipes? E.g. `echo "y yes" | ./your_program`

Comment: you can try `yes` command: `yes | ./your_program`. more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That may or may not work, depending on how the script or program handles stdin. As an example, you can't really script an SSH or FTP session that way via a pipe.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg @MaddineniAbhilash most scripts will read from stdin line by line, because of that `echo "y yes" | ./your_program` will not work, you will have to do it like this: `echo -e "y\nyes" | ./your_program` or `(echo "y"; echo "yes") | ./your_program` (assuming that your scripts expects only two inputs, otherwise you will have to add an additional `echo` for each additional expected input... or use expect(http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) if you to do some really really complicated automated interaction

Answer (score 0):

### Use *yes* Utility

You can use the *yes* command if you always want to pass the same value. For example:

```
yes | ./script.sh
```

### Use Expect, Variables, or Configuration Files

If you need anything more complex, then *yes* usually can't do what you want directly. Instead, you should use *expect* to script complex interactions, or rewrite your shell scripts to use variables or configuration files to pass parameters.